# Sailjs have different session for admin route and customer route

Tags: session, sails.js, ejs

I have a sailsjs app where in the customer routes are served from
/* And the admin route is /admin/*

How to maintain two different session for these routes.

Right now if I login in /admin and navigate to /* it shows me the customer pages and keeps me logged in as admin.

Answer (score 1):

You can create 1 session variable that defines the type of user. For the admin section , and 1 different variable for the customer section.
When you login on each section you would erase the variable of the other section and set the one for the correspnding section.

```
env.req.session.typeofuser = 'customer';
```

Then to check in your admin section actions you can use something like :

```
fn: async function (inputs,exits,env) {
if (env.req.session.typeofuser === 'customer'){ throw { nosession: '/' }; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Handled it using a Custom Hook wherein I have two route based session handlers like

```
  */
      before: {
        "/admin/*":{...},
        "/*": {
          skipRegex:/[/](?:admin)\S+/gm,
           ......}
    }
```